# Typescript doesn't narrow on function constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-class, type-narrowing

I'm using a constructor function named DNSHandler whose interface looks like:

```js
interface DNSHandler {
    received: Partial<DNSStandardQuery>;
    ParseDNSStandardQuery(): boolean;
    __parseDomain(domainBuf: Buffer): string;
}
```

where DNSStandardQuery's interface contains a number of properties that I'd like to fill during calling DNSHandler's `ParseDNSStandardQuery()`.

So in DNSStandardQuery's constructor I initialized `this.received` to an empty object, and filled it's first property - `rawQuery` with `DNSBuffer: Buffer`:

```js
this.received = {};
this.received.rawQuery = DNSBuffer;
```

But when I reference `this.received.rawQuery` in the `ParseDNSStadndardQuery()` method:

```js
this.ParseDNSStadndardQuery = function() {
    if (this.received.rawQuery.length < 21) {...}
}
```

I get:

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'. TS(2532)
```

I understand that I get it because `this.received` is declared as `Partial` type, but I was expecting that it'll be narrowed in the constructor section.

What did I miss?

Entire (minimal) example below, as every `buff = this.received.rawQuery` reference is encountered `Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)` error:

```
const DOT_ASCII = 46;


interface DNSStandardQuery{
    rawQuery: Buffer;
    transactiodID: number;
    flags: number;
    questions: number;
    type: number;
    class: number;
    domain: string;
}

interface DNSHandler{
    received: Partial<DNSStandardQuery>;
    ParseDNSStadndardQuery(): void;
    __parseDomain(domainBuf: Buffer): string;
}

const DNSHandler = function(this: DNSHandler, DNSBuffer: Buffer){
    this.received = {};
    this.received.rawQuery = DNSBuffer;
    // Only handles standard queries with single question, with  type 'A' internet class queries.
    this.ParseDNSStadndardQuery = function(){
        let received = this.received;
        let buff = this.received.rawQuery;
        if (this.received.rawQuery.length < 21) {console.error("Got too short message"); return false;}
        received.transactiodID = parseShort(buff[0], buff[1]);
        received.flags = parseShort(buff[2], buff[3]);
        received.questions = parseShort(buff[4], buff[5]);
        received.class = parseShort(buff[buff.length - 2], buff[buff.length - 1])
        received.type = parseShort(buff[buff.length - 4], buff[buff.length - 3])
        received.domain = this.__parseDomain(buff.slice(12, buff.length-4));
    }

    this.__parseDomain = function(domainBuf: Buffer){
        let domain = [];
        let bytesToRead = domainBuf[0];
        while(bytesToRead){
            domain.push(...domainBuf.slice(1, bytesToRead+1) as unknown as number[],DOT_ASCII);
            domainBuf = domainBuf.slice(bytesToRead+1);
            bytesToRead = domainBuf[0];
        }
        // Remove trailed DOT
        return String.fromCharCode(...domain.slice(0, domain.length-1));
    }
} as any as {new(DNSBuffer: Buffer): DNSHandler}
```

Comment: You've given us too little code, and your explanation is too ambiguous and does not fill the gaps. Why don't you post all of the code at the end of the question? What you really should do is provide an [mre]. By creating an [mre], you will narrow the problem to its essence and my solve the problem by yourself!

Comment: `received: Partial<DNSStandardQuery>`  means `received` could be  an empty object. You may have set it at some point but TS cannot really reliably know that when the function you mention gets called the property you want to use has been defined

Comment: @Inigo Updated. thanks for the feedback, it's my first question here :)

Comment: @apokryfos So what is recommended to do in such situations?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some tries to find the best solution for this case, I found a promising one

Instead of declaring the property as a partial one like I did before:

```
interface DNSHandler{
    received: Partial<DNSStandardQuery>;
    ParseDNSStadndardQuery(): boolean;
    __parseDomain(domainBuf: Buffer): string;
}
```

you can declare the property in the usual way:

```
interface DNSHandler{
    received: Partial<DNSStandardQuery>;
    ParseDNSStadndardQuery(): boolean;
    __parseDomain(domainBuf: Buffer): string;
}
```

and then initialize the object with {} syntax:

```
const DNSHandler = function(this: DNSHandler, DNSBuffer: Buffer){
    this.received = <DNSStandardQuery>{};
...
}
```